# How can I define a generic function that can return a given integer type?

Tags: rust

I'd like to define a function that can return a number whose type is specified when the function is called. The function takes a buffer (`Vec<u8>`) and returns numeric value, e.g.

```rust
let byte = buf_to_num<u8>(&buf);
let integer = buf_to_num<u32>(&buf);
```

The buffer contains an ASCII string that represents a number, e.g. `b"827"`, where each byte is the ASCII code of a digit.

This is my non-working code:

```rust
  extern crate num;
  use num::Integer;
  use std::ops::{MulAssign, AddAssign};

  fn buf_to_num<T: Integer + MulAssign + AddAssign>(buf: &Vec::<u8>) -> T {
    let mut result : T;
    for byte in buf {
      result *= 10;
      result += (byte - b'0');
    }
    result
  }
```

I get mismatched type errors for both the addition and the multiplication lines (`expected type T, found u32`). So I guess my problem is how to tell the type system that `T` can be expressed in terms of a literal `10` or in terms of the result of `(byte - b'0')`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to the joys of having to specify every single operation you're using as a generic. It's a pain, but it is worth.

You have two problems:

1. `result *= 10;` without a corresponding `From<_>` definition. This is because, when you specify "10", there is no way for the compiler to know what "10" as a `T` means - it knows primitive types, and any conversion you defined by implementing `From<_>` traits
2. You're mixing up two operations - coercion from a vector of characters to an integer, and your operation.

We need to make two assumptions for this:

- We will require `From<u32>` so we can cap our numbers to `u32`
- We will also clarify your logic and convert each `u8` to `char` so we can use `to_digit()` to convert *that* to `u32`, before making use of `From<u32>` to get a `T`.

  ```
  use std::ops::{MulAssign, AddAssign};
  fn parse_to_i<T: From<u32> + MulAssign + AddAssign>(buf: &[u8]) -> T {
      let mut buffer:T = (0 as u32).into();
      for o in buf {
          buffer *= 10.into();
          buffer += (*o as char).to_digit(10).unwrap_or(0).into();
      }
      buffer
  }
  ```

You can convince yourself of its behavior [**on the playground**](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=60807e59ed4380e111e90cb398492d85)

The multiplication is resolved by force-casting the constant as `u8`, which makes it benefit from our requirement of `From<u8>` for T and allows the rust compiler to know we're not doing silly stuff.

The final change is to set `result` to have a default value of 0.

Let me know if this makes sense to you (or if it doesn't), and I'll be glad to elaborate further if there is a problem :-)

Comment: Thanks, that helps a lot, but this part: *result += (byte - b'0'); is a kludge and lacks the Sub definition* confuses me. I think `*byte` is different from what I'm doing. My intention is to read the buffer that contains ASCII data as bytes and convert it into a number. `*byte` is going to be the ASCII code of `0..9`, not `0..9`. I'll edit the question to add this detail, sorry for not mentioning it.

Comment: @TamásSzelei Yeah, that's a *huge* difference. Editing my answer to match.

Comment: @TamásSzelei corrected. I've implemented the proper conversion from an ASCII char array to a number for you :-)

Comment: Thanks! This indeed works well for the u32 case, but I also want the function to be able to return u8 as well. If I change the test the number 122 and `T` to `u8`, I get `the trait bound u8: std::convert::From<u32> is not satisfied`. I tried adding another `From` bound, but that made it blow up with errors I'm not able to decipher.

Comment: I'll be through airport security in a tiny bit; when I am, I'll edit further, although what I will give you is an even more generic answer. I don't believe it is worth it personally, as it is easier to down convert an `u32` down to `u8` than the reverse (hint: not possible)

Comment: @TamásSzelei Actually, I was looking over it. You gain nothing but complications by requiring the inner state to be an `u8` vs. a `u32` as `to_digit()` is defined as [`fn to_digit(self, radix: u32) -> Option<u32>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.char.html#method.to_digit), which means not going for a `u32` requires intermediate conversions at every step via `TryFrom`. Really, really not worth, particularly for an intermediate state that never leaks out.

Comment: So are you suggesting that "casting" the known u8 values is a better idea then?

Comment: That's not where the `u8`/`u32` debate is. Parsing an ASCII digit using `char` returns an `u32`, and that's where the point of contention is. [Doing away with it is doable](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=ed5f2fe6b607e626bb2bd014d08426c1) but requires an intermediate generic and *tons* of conversions.

Comment: @TamásSzelei to be precise, the *only* place where `u32` is explicitly required is `buffer += (*o as char).to_digit(10).unwrap_or(0).into();`. The rest could be done with `From<R>` where `R` is numeric as long as `Into<R>` exists.

Comment: Fair enough, thanks a lot for extended discussion - I guess I overreached a bit with my first rust project :) but I learned a lot from this. I ended up removing all generics (just returning a fixed `u32`) and using `value.to_le_bytes()[0]` where I want a `u8` (when I know the value fits in a `u8`).

Comment: @TamásSzelei overextension and discussions are two of the three main ways to learn! (The third one being not doing things right). There was no harm done and, to be honest, I've also benefited a bit from having to think of a way to fit your requirements. Keep them going and have fun with Rust :-)